# Find an edge in a connected undirected graph that doesn't belong to at least one MST

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I'm studying for my algorithms test and came across this question, I'm stuck and would appreciate help in finding a solution.

***Question:***

Given a connected undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ and a weight function on the edges $w:E{\rightarrow}R$,

Devise an algorithm that returns $e{\in}E$  that doesn't belong to at least one MST (minimal spanning tree) of G, or determines one doesn't exist.

Comment: Is MST a Maximal Spanning Tree?

Comment: A naive approach if all weights are different: Prim's algorithm is deterministic way to find the MST of a graph and only requires a single initial choice: The first edge. If the first edge is part of a MST, it will be returned in the output (if there are no other edges with the same weight, which was assumed). So simply run Prim's algorithm with every possible initial input edge ($|V|$ times), and note how many times each edge was contained in the output. Afterwards, take all edges where $0$ was noted.

Comment: Minimal spanning tree, I would put it in the question description. A friend helped me with an algorithm that takes linear time using DFS (you run DFS once to obtain a spanning tree, then select an edge that isn't in that tree, add it to the spanning tree, you created a circle, so you run DFS again to find the circle, and return the heaviest edge in that circle).

Comment: yes that method proposed by your friend sounds great, why are you still stuck ?

Comment: One way: for each edge $e$, check what happens when you compute a MST of $G - e$.